# My system won't boot after install of 12.10

Tags: installation, boot, 12.10

I just finished installing 12.10 on my desktop. I chose to erase the current data on the drive and start fresh. When my system attempts to boot now, it doesn't see an available operating system at all. I have tried using boot-repair to no avail. Is there anyway to get my system back into a bootable state?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to boot by setting my bios to use only legacy boot instead of UEFI. Then I reinstalled.